# How to Sum the Total salary column by adding the Salary Column

Tags: sql-server

| Cola | Salary | TotalSalary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 100 |
| B | 200 | 300 |
| C | 300 | 600 |

Comment: That's why they wrote the documentation on `sum()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum()` window function to get a running total:

```
select Cola,
Salary,
Sum(Salary) over(order by Cola rows unbounded preceding) as TotalSalary
from yourtable;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ffd0c6695466e6b0db95f413bffc3dfa)

Comment: Thanks zakaria and why do we use rows unbounded preceding